# Running iSCSI LIO with high availability

Tags: high-availability, iscsi, ocfs2

I've build a two node storage setup with OCFS on top of DRBD to provide storage for a couple of ESXi servers. Will it be possible to setup iSCSI targets on both storage nodes and make one of the nodes take over the other in case of server failure?

If any other similar setups would let me achieve this, please let me know.

Howto's are very welcome.